# Seeking shapefile for project work in India

Tags: geospatial, city, india

Can anyone provide the shapefile of KOZHIKODE City (not the district), and the same for BHUJ city as well?

I tried the district file, but I need the city's shapefile, not the entire district.

Comment: Isn't it possible to extract any city data from the entire district?

Answer (score 4):

As @PolyGeo said, this is a question for [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). But you can get a such data from [here](https://github.com/geohacker/kerala) (although they might be a bit outdated). It contains the KOZHIKODE City for sure. I imported the *village.shp* and I think that's where Kozhikode city is.

[image: kozi city]

You can download the data:

[image: dl data]